# Faster Way to Filter?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, filter

I have an array of type `"Option"`.

The class `Option`contains an element `optionDetail`.

The class `optionDetail` contains elements of `detailTraits`, which is an `[String]` with each string being called the `detailTraitName`.

So my structure of getting the detailTraits looks like `Option` -> `optionDetail` -> `detailTraits`which would return me `[String]`, or `Option` -> `optionDetail` -> `detailTraits` -> `detailTraitName`, which would return me just one String

I would like to match up the `detailTraits` array with another array, named `selectedDetails`, which is an `[String]` and find the elements in which all of the `selectedDetails` are contained inside of the `detailTraits`. I then want to return all of the `Option` in which this situation is true.

For example, if my `selectedDetails` array contains `["A", "B"]`, and I have one `detailTraits` array that has `["A","C"]` and one that has `["A"]` and one that has `["A", "B", "C"]`, I just want to return the option which had `detailTraits` of `["A", "B", "C"]`

My current code looks like the following:

`newOptions = option.filter({ $0.optionDetail?.detailTraits.filter({ selectedDetails.contains($0.detailTraitName ?? "") }).count == selectedDetails.count })`

Is there a better way to do this? This algorithm seems pretty inefficient since It's probably in the order of magnitude of N^3, but I can't think of a better way to look through an array of arrays and match it to another array.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the definition of the `Option` class

Answer (score 0):

You can optimise this by first filtering by comparing `count` on `selectedDetails` and `detailTraits`, and then comparing actual values. This way options set would be reduced to only those `detailTraits` having exact same count. For example you would only need to compare the string values with array containing exact 3 items (if `selectedDetails` is `["A", "B", "C"]`), completely avoiding one iteration in loop.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's important to sort `detailTraits` alphabetically before-hand, that way you can simply compare `selectedDetails` with the same amount items from the beginning of the `detailTraits`.

Comment: Its going to be iterated N times in any case.

Comment: Yes, but if the items are pre-sorted, the compare operation is simplified (e.g. are `["A", "B", "C"]` and `["A", "B", "C"]` equal?). If the items are not presorted, each compare operation must first determine if the elements are the same but ordered differently (e.g. `["A", "B", "C"]` and `["C", "B", "A"]`).

Comment: Apologies, I thought you are talking about `detailTraits` sorted by `count`

Comment: I overlooked an important detail, sorting won't help as the items are not necessarily at the beginning of the array (e.g. `selectedDetails` is `["B"]` and `detailTraits` is `["A", "B"]`, which is actually a match).